# I want to load an HTML file into my JSON

Tags: jquery, json, html, file, load

I want to load/inject an HTML file into my JSON using `$.get()` function or  another way.

```
{
  "person": {
    "name":$.get( 'name.html' )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way::

```
var file_data = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "name.html", async: false}).responseText;
```

**JSON**

```
{
"person":{
           "name": file_data
         }
}
```

Comment: This works also

{

"person":{
           "name": $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "name.html", async: false}).responseText
         }
}